# How to install Microsoft Teams and login to it automatically using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to write a script that will open Microsoft Teams app and login to it automatically. The plan is to automate our process so we do not have to type the email and the password for each computer setup. I tried the `Connect-Microsoft Teams` command but that will login to Teams in PowerShell not in Teams app. When I open the app it still asking me for credentials.

Comment: Research if teams app has command-line parameters to pass credentials. If not, you'll need UI automation to enter credentials programmatically. Teams 1.x is Electron-based (which uses Chromium under the hood), so it might be beneficial to research automation of Electron/Chromium-based apps specifically.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any way via PowerShell to install MS Teams and login to it automatically